# Stateless widget to stateful widget ( using Create state)

Tags: flutter, dart

[error][1]

```
void main() {
  runApp(MyApp());
}
class MyApp extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  State<StatefulWidget> createState() {
    // TODO: implement createState
    return MyAppState();
  }
}
class MyAppState extends State<MyApp> {
  var questionIndex = 0;

  void answerQuestion() {
    setState(() {
      questionIndex = questionIndex + 1;
    });
    print(questionIndex);
  }
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    var question = [
      'what\'s your favorite colour?',
      'what\'s your favorite sports?',
    ];
    return MaterialApp(
      home: Scaffold(
        appBar: AppBar(
          title: Text('My app'),
        ),
        body: Column(
          children: [
            Text(question[questionIndex]),
            RaisedButton(
              child: Text('answer1'),
              onPressed: () => print('answer2'),
            ),
            RaisedButton(
              child: Text('answer2'),
              onPressed: () => print('answer2'),
            ),
            RaisedButton(
                child: Text('answer3'),
                onPressed: () {
                  print('answer3');
                }),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

**error
I'm on going course in Udemy in that they got the output for the same code but for me it showing error like this **
** Exception caught by widgets library**
** MyAppState#f6d27(lifecycle state: created, no widget, not mounted)**
[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/NFGhN.jpg

Comment: Your code runs just fine

Answer (score 1):

You need to create a private class.

```
class FilmList extends StatefulWidget {
  const FilmList({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  _FilmListState createState() => _FilmListState();//need to add
}

class _FilmListState extends State<FilmList> {
  MovieQuery query = MovieQuery.year;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(),
child:Container(),
);}
}
```